# Troubles with CSS height in percentage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's a bit difficult for me to explain my problem, so much better to just show an example (check the JSFiddle):

```
#contacts {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
max-height: 75%;
}
#contacts .tab-content {
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle no scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/1shn0xad/1/)

As you see, there's a tab fixed on the bottom which toggles a panel (I'm using Bootstrap 3). The content of the panel is dynamically generated, so I need the panel to increase its height as the content is generated, up to a 75% of the page's height (not to cover it all).
Now, when the content is too much, I need an inner scrollbar; as you can see, the scrollbar is there, but it's not working, because the #contacts div has no specific height, so the .tab-content's "height: 100%" is not working.
If I try using "overflow: scroll" on #contacts instead of .tab-content, it works:

[JSFiddle scrolls label too](http://jsfiddle.net/xpfw25z3/)

But the problem, now, is that the scrollbar also scrolls the tab label, and that it's outside of the .tab-content, so when I click on it the div loses focus and the tab closes.
Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Proof of Concept Solution**

I boiled down the design problem to the basics (without Bootstrap).

The `.fixed-wrapper` is pinned to the bottom of the page using `position: fixed`, and apply `overflow-y: scroll` to enable scrolling.

The `.header` tab element is also positioned fixed, but the trick is to set the bottom offset to the same value as the max-height value of `.fixed-wrapper`, 60% in this example.

Then you toggle the content, you need to adjust the following:

```
.fixed-wrapper { max-height: 0;}
.header { bottom: 0;}
.scroll-panel { display: none;}
```

If you have an `.active` class to distinguish the display state, your CSS might look like:

```
.fixed-wrapper.active { max-height: 60%;}
.fixed-wrapper.active .header { bottom: 60%;}
.fixed-wrapper.active .scroll-panel { display: bottom;}
```

When applying this to a Bootstrap layout, make sure that your selectors are specific enough so that the Bootstrap classes do not override the key rules shown above.

Note: There is a minor limitation to this solution.  If the content is insufficiently tall to force scrolling, then the header element may hang at the
60% position even though the `.scroll-panel` does not reach the max-height.  You may need some JavaScript to take care of that.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
p {
    line-height: 2.0;
}
.fixed-wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
    max-height: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.header {
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60%;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: auto;
}
.scroll-panel {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-wrapper">
    <div class="header">header or tab...</div>
    <div class="scroll-panel">
        <p>Some content...</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing. Pellentesque consequat laoreet sagittis. Sed sit amet erat augue. Morbi consectetur, elit quis iaculis cursus, mauris nulla hendrerit augue, ut faucibus elit sapien vitae justo. In a ipsum malesuada nulla rutrum luctus. Donec a enim sapien. Sed ultrices ligula ac neque vulputate luctus. Suspendisse pretium pretium felis, in aliquet risus fringilla at. Nunc cursus sagittis commodo.</p>        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing. Pellentesque consequat laoreet sagittis. Sed sit amet erat augue. Morbi consectetur, elit quis iaculis cursus, mauris nulla hendrerit augue, ut faucibus elit sapien vitae justo. In a ipsum malesuada nulla rutrum luctus. Donec a enim sapien. Sed ultrices ligula ac neque vulputate luctus. Suspendisse pretium pretium felis, in aliquet risus fringilla at. Nunc cursus sagittis commodo.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this way, when I open the tab, the label will go up to 60% even if the panel is shorter, isn't it? And it will detach from the panel, which wouldn't look good.

Comment: Indeed, that is the problem with this solution.  The header/tab needs to be fixed so that it does not scroll, but once the position is fixed, the header/tab element is out of the content flow so there is no way CSS can compute the height of the content and hence set the bottom offset to the needed value.  However, jQuery/JavaScript could fix that.  If your design could work with a fixed height, then this would work.

Comment: Fixed height wouldn't work as the panel content will be generated dynamically, so it starts almost empty and then fills up. So there is no way to make the .tab-content div as tall as the #contacts div? Or make it 75% of the body's height, instead of the #contact? How should I approach this in JS if nothing else is possible?

Comment: Based on what you described, upon activation, the panel's height would start to increase up to max height as content is added through some polling mechanism (reminds me of a chat window).  If you are using AJAX to get the generated content, you could then use jQuery/JavaScript to get the height of the content panel and adjust the layout.  You need to think of what will trigger the re-sizing calculation...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but no AJAX, just preloaded form inputs showing while filling it. I guess I'll just put a max-height in pixels to the .tab-content, and edit that value with JS when the tab is activated (it won't resize when resizing the window, but seems good enough!).

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I looked at it again and it is indeed a pain, but this seems to work (a bit ugly though): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1shn0xad/8/)

```
#contacts {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 75%;
    overflow-y: hidden;

}
#contacts .tab-content {
    background-color: #ccc;   
}

.tab-pane {
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#contacts ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
#contacts > ul > li > a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: i am unable to scroll the content ...the moment i scroll the div hides

Comment: I know I was aware of making a mistake see comment, but his code in his post suggested that he didn't specify an overflow value.

Comment: I didn't notice your last edit. That doesn't work because on short screens, the scrollbar gets lost below the page.By the way, I solved using a max-height value in pixels rather than %. This way, the child div can get 100% height.